# Scrolling text object for macOS

Tags: macos, text, scroll, swift3

I have almost completed my first app for Mac. This app is a client that when you click on a button write inside a txt file on a Dropbox folder, the server side check the file and based and what write, do something, and then rewrite the file with a report that my client app display.

I have done everything but when I ask for a "status" command the server answer with a very long report and my label and initial window size cannot display all and I must enlarge the window. I would like to make the label scrollable so I can make my app more easy to use. It should be something really similar to UITextView in iOS development.

I am coding in Swift3.

Thank you,
Matteo Collina

Comment: I don't follow. Are you asking for the equivalent of UITextView? In this case: NSTextView. If not: what are you asking?

Comment: Yes and no, I mean that I want an object that can display a scrollable text like UITextView do on iOS.

Comment: NSTextView is what you want. It can scroll, wrap, truncate, edit, etc.

Comment: does NSTextView have .write or .stringvalue method?

Comment: SOLVED! :-) just one thing, can I add a padding inside the TextView?